# Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu not saving panel locations

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, netbeans

Whenever I fire up netbeans on ubuntu the locations of the panels from my last session is not saved, unlike the behavior on windows.

I installed netbeans using OS independent package not through the package manager, and placed the extracted folder to /opt/netbeans

Everything works ok, but for example the netbeans "Output" panel always appears next to my source files, if I drag it to the bottom it stays there until I close netbeans and re-open it again, it re-appears besides my source files. Same thing applies for any panel I try to change positions, it gets really annoying when debugging, as i get 3 or 4 panels besides my source files instead of them being docked nicely in the bottom.

Is there any config file i need to change in order to fix this?

I asked this same quesiton on stackoverflow, but a suggestion was to post it here, so sorry if this is not the right place for it

[Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434429/netbeans-on-ubuntu-not-saving-panel-locations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually got an answer to this on Stackoverflow.
If anyone is interested here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434429/netbeans-on-ubuntu-not-saving-panel-locations